# How get request and response unique tag in Haproxy with Lua

Tags: lua, haproxy

I read Haproxy doc and find option forceclose, want know in Haproxy whether or not have a unique key with a request and response with Lua.
[enter link description here](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#option%20forceclose)

Thinks

Comment: It is not clear what you or asking.  Please provide additional information to explain what you are trying to accomplish and now a unique key is related to `option forceclose`.

Comment: sorry, I mean is Haproxy has request and response.  and in Haproxy, How to get the request and response one-to-one correspondence. like  i buy a product, the product has a ibs.   Complete the request  ibs is what?   My native language is not English, sorry